# Required torque to move 6000kg at 27.77m/s

Tags: torque

I'm trying to find the required Newton or Nm of torque to move 6000 kg up a grade at 100 km/h.

I'm trying to work out the closest suited engine platform to do the job while been efficient, durable,cost effective and most of all required torque.

- Mass: 6000 kg
- Speed: 27.77 m/s = 100 km/h
- Grade: 7° = 12%
- Wheel size: 830 mm

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: No it is not, general question. I am looking repowering or upgrading my vehicle and my calculations seem to unlikely at best.

Comment: Hi @Q.stratford it would be great if you could supply us with a simple sketch. I am not sure if I understand the setup. Are you assuming that friction can be neglected? And do you have any specifications for the rate of acceleration of the 6000kg mass?

Comment: if you have calculations, show what you've done so far and we can check.  Beyond that, my suggestion is to start with energy, not torque.  Work out how much horesepower you need to lift the given mass at the given vertical rate.  After that, you can calculate torque from the power and the wheel RPM.

Comment: The acceleration required is a key point - and is it able to have a run-up on the flat to reach the required speed? The speed itself is not connected to the torque required to pull a mass up a slope, unless it affects the friction/air resistance, which we know nothing about. More information required!

Comment: You need power for the speed.  Show what you have so far.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a "[homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832)" (notice the quotation marks). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: Hi the speed is to be constant at 27.77 m/s or 100kmh as to maintain this speed from the start of the grade to the top.

Comment: Hi the speed is constant, so the vehicle will be traveling at this velocity prior to the grade. Im at this point im not ignoring inefficiencies im just trying to work out a base figure  but from what i understand  drag coefficent is 0.6, drive train loss of 20%, rolling resistance of 0.02 ( these figures may not be correct). Also i am not trying to work out hp as diesels are different to petrols and torque and hp dont realy coinside.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not an engineering question as posed.  The answer for you is to go down to your local chevy dealer, tell him what you need to haul, and look up the torque specs on the engine in a suitable size truck.

Comment: **I think it is not a homework. It is homemade.** Maybe the OP is trying to build a homemade trebuchet or similar. I think it is ontopic.

Answer (score 3):

To overcome hill resistance, you need **2977 Nm or 2195 ft*lbs** of torque at the wheels.
Assumed that the gravitional acceleration in your situation is $9.81m/s^2$, as it approximtely is everywhere on Earth, your weight is:

$F_g=m*g=6000kg*9.81=58860N$

The hill resistance which drags you backwards is  :

$F_h=sin(a)*F_g=sin(7deg)*58860=7173N$

To keep any given speed, the force must be the same at the outer side of your wheel. So any speed that is achieved, is maintained. (theoretically, no friction included)

Assumed you meant that the diameter(not radius) of your wheels is 830mm,
this translates in a torque **at the wheels** of

$T_w=F*r=7173*(0.830/2)=2977Nm$

To drive your vehicle to the speed of 27.78m/s up a hill of 7 degrees, you need

$P=F*v=7173 * 27.78 = 199.257 kW$ (or roughly 270hp)

of power, when there wouldn't be any friction.

But there will be friction, so you'll need more power and torque. This isn't calculable though, since there isn't enough information supplied in the question. At a normal asphalt road with an expectable loaded truck of 6 tonnes, i'd guess that you need roughly 50% more power, and therefore 50% more torque at the same speed. You also need a margin to accelerate to that speed in not-too-much time. **NB:** this is just a wild guess, don't rely on it for any important decisions.

Don't forget that the transmission in a vehicle will lower the torque demand at the motor, at the price of the demand for a higher angular speed of the engine, relative to that of the wheels.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for power, not torque. Torque (together with RPM) is just one of the factors for calculating power and can be amplified or reduced by using gears. It is not possible to just give a needed torque figure for an engine.

All in all there are too many variables missing anyway.
For all i know we could be talking about a moving vehicle or a stationary setup like a cable elevator, which could lead to a different solution.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering.SE, a Question and Answer site. This is not an answer, it is a request for clarification. As such, it should have been posted as a comment and not an Answer. Once you get more rep you'll be able to post comments.